# Sitecore: Valid item names

Tags: web-config, sitecore, names

How do I expand the list of valid characters in item names, to include æøåÆØÅ?

As per default the valid characters seems to be defined by this rule in web.config:

```
 <setting name="ItemNameValidation" value="^[\w\*\$][\w\s\-\$]*(\(\d{1,}\)){0,1}$" />
```

changing the regex to :

```
<setting name="ItemNameValidation" value="^[\wæøåÆØÅ\*\$][\wæøåÆØÅ\s\-\$]*(\(\d{1,}\)){0,1}$" />
```

Should in theory allow the characters, but that just "kills" the sitecore.

Edit:
A regex that allows dots, are working perfectly like this:

```
<setting name="ItemNameValidation" value="^[\w\*\$][\w\.\s\-\$]*(\(\d{1,}\)){0,1}$" />
```

So I am allowed to change some aspects of it, just not for the æøå characters?!?!?

Note:
  - Using æøå in item names is for some reason possible from the "Page Editor", when creating and saving new content items, but it is not possible to do the same from the "Content Editor"!
  - We are using SC v6.6.0 (rev. 120918).

**Cause of error was not saving the file as UTF-8**

Comment: You should probably avoid those characters in the item names unless you want bizarre looking HTML encoded URLs. You can use those characters in the display name attribute of the item instead.

Comment: works fine in my local machine. i'm using Sitecore 6.5.0 rev. 121009 and your updated regex

Comment: How odd. Im getting "500 - Internal Server Error", whenever I do that.

Comment: Make sure your config file is saved as "UTF-8"

Comment: @Sandbeck : Ofcouse! That was indeed what were causing the error, thanks alot =)

Comment: I'd suggest Sandbeck add this as an official answer and you accept that, so he can be awarded the rep points.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure your config file is saved as "UTF-8"

A bit late, but adding as an answer :)

Answer (score 2):

Cause of error was not saving the file as UTF-8